Get libp2p Secp256k1PeerId from ethereum public key
I have a eth public key 0x123..., and I'd like to get its corresponding Secp256k1 peer id (e.g. 16Uiu...)
The @libp2p package has createSecp256k1PeerId() but it doesn't take any parameters. It also has createFromPubKey(publicKey) which returns Ed25519PeerId | Secp256k1PeerId | RSAPeerId, but I'm not sure the format publicKey should be in to get a Secp256k1PeerId out.
How can I perform this eth public key hex string -> Secp256k1PeerId conversion?
